# Change CAGradientLayer location with animation

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

Here are the two variations in the locations on a screen which I want to display :

[image]

---

---

[image]

---

---

I am able to get this effect by following code :

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        let color1 = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 231.0/255.0, blue: 198.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9).cgColor as CGColor
        let color2 = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 198.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9).cgColor as CGColor

        self.gradientLayer.colors = [color2, color1, color2]
        self.gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.60, 1]
        self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        viewMain.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradientLayer, at: 0)
        img.addSubview(viewMain)
        img.bringSubview(toFront: viewMain)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.imageLogo)

        self.gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2, color1]
        self.gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.60, 1]
        self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        viewMain.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradientLayer, at: 0)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
                self.gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2, color1]
                self.gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.60, 1]
                self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
                viewMain.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradientLayer, at: 0)
        })
```

But this is not giving me a smooth transition from first variation to the second one. How may I do that ?

Comment: `colors` is animable, it seems that the only thing that is really changing. What about using that?

Comment: Have you tried using a `CABasicAnimation` to perform the animation?

Comment: @Larme : Let me check on that.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist : Not yet. Tried UIView animation, but it didn't work.

Comment: UIView Animation is not the proper way to do this when you are dealing with a CALayer, you definitely want to employ a CABasicAnimation